# Why does this ASM function call refrence a memory location just one byte ahead?

Tags: go, assembly, x86, operating-system

I am trying to compile Go for an operating system (without any standard go libraries whatsoever), and I wrote this go program:
(ignore the fact that I'm using Go, yes, I know it will be painful)

```
package main

import (
    "unsafe"
)

// return an array with dimensions 25x80x2, at mem location addr
var vidMem *[25][80][2]byte
func get_vidMem(addr uint32) *[25][80][2]byte {
    buff := (*[25][80][2]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(addr)))
    return buff 
}

func main() {
    var outcolor uint8 = 0x7
    var outchar uint8 = 'L'
    vidMem = get_vidMem(0xB8000)
    vidMem[0][0][0] = outcolor
    vidMem[0][0][1] = outchar
}
```

The code I wrote didn't work, so I passed it through objdump, and got this:

```
main.obj:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main.get__vidMem>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
   6:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
   d:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  10:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],eax
  13:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
  16:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
  19:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
  1c:   c9                      leave
  1d:   c3                      ret

0000001e <main.main>:
  1e:   55                      push   ebp
  1f:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  21:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
  24:   c6 45 f7 07             mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],0x7
  28:   c6 45 f6 4c             mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0xa],0x4c
  2c:   83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc
  2f:   68 00 80 0b 00          push   0xb8000
  34:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   35 <main.main+0x17>
  39:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  3c:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x0
  41:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x0
  46:   8b 09                   mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ecx]
  48:   85 c9                   test   ecx,ecx
  4a:   75 04                   jne    50 <main.main+0x32>
  4c:   89 02                   mov    DWORD PTR [edx],eax
  4e:   eb 0d                   jmp    5d <main.main+0x3f>
  50:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
  53:   50                      push   eax
  54:   52                      push   edx
  55:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   56 <main.main+0x38>
  5a:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  5d:   a1 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x0
  62:   0f b6 55 f7             movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9]
  66:   88 10                   mov    BYTE PTR [eax],dl
  68:   a1 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x0
  6d:   0f b6 55 f6             movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [ebp-0xa]
  71:   88 50 01                mov    BYTE PTR [eax+0x1],dl
  74:   c9                      leave
  75:   c3                      ret

00000076 <main._625_7_680_7_62_7uint8..eq>:
  76:   55                      push   ebp
  77:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  79:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
  7c:   c6 45 f7 00             mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],0x0
  80:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
  83:   68 a0 0f 00 00          push   0xfa0
  88:   ff 75 0c                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
  8b:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  8e:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   8f <main._625_7_680_7_62_7uint8..eq+0x19>
  93:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  96:   88 45 f7                mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],al
  99:   0f b6 45 f7             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9]
  9d:   c9                      leave
  9e:   c3                      ret

0000009f <main._680_7_62_7uint8..eq>:
  9f:   55                      push   ebp
  a0:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  a2:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
  a5:   c6 45 f7 00             mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],0x0
  a9:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
  ac:   68 a0 00 00 00          push   0xa0
  b1:   ff 75 0c                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
  b4:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  b7:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   b8 <main._680_7_62_7uint8..eq+0x19>
  bc:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  bf:   88 45 f7                mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],al
  c2:   0f b6 45 f7             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9]
  c6:   c9                      leave
  c7:   c3                      ret

000000c8 <main._62_7uint8..eq>:
  c8:   55                      push   ebp
  c9:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  cb:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
  ce:   c6 45 f7 00             mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],0x0
  d2:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
  d5:   6a 02                   push   0x2
  d7:   ff 75 0c                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
  da:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  dd:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   de <main._62_7uint8..eq+0x16>
  e2:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  e5:   88 45 f7                mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],al
  e8:   0f b6 45 f7             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9]
  ec:   c9                      leave
  ed:   c3                      ret

000000ee <__go_init_main>:
  ee:   55                      push   ebp
  ef:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  f1:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
  f4:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
  f7:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  fc:   6a 01                   push   0x1
  fe:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   ff <__go_init_main+0x11>
 103:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 106:   83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc
 109:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
 10e:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   10f <__go_init_main+0x21>
 113:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 116:   c9                      leave
 117:   c3                      ret
```

I quickly noticed this piece of code that stood out to me:

```
  2f:   68 00 80 0b 00          push   0xb8000
  34:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   35 <main.main+0x17>  # right here
  39:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
  3c:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x0
  41:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x0
  46:   8b 09                   mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ecx]
  48:   85 c9                   test   ecx,ecx
  4a:   75 04                   jne    50 <main.main+0x32>
  4c:   89 02                   mov    DWORD PTR [edx],eax
  4e:   eb 0d                   jmp    5d <main.main+0x3f>
  50:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
```

Why is it executing `call` to that address, and what does it do?

I am using this command to compile: `i686-elf-gccgo -static -Werror -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -c main.go -o main.obj`

Comment: You're disassembling a `.obj`, not a linked executable.  The `rel32` displacements are just placeholders.  (The 1 byte is probably the difference between the instruction start vs. the start of the rel32, if the relocation entries are relative to the start of the rel32, but x86 jumps are relative to the end of the instruction).  As Jester says, use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`, with the `-r` being the key part.

Comment: You can use `objdump -dr` to see relocation entries, that will tell you where the `call` is supposed to go (pun intended :))

Comment: Near duplicate of [objdump and resolving linkage of local function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8992938) / [What are these seemingly-useless callq instructions in my x86 object files for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34793452)